# ERROR /usr/libexec/mysqld: Error writing file '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid' (Errcode: 28)

Tags: mysql, linux

Currently I am facing a problem with mysql on Linux Centos. It was stopped abruptly.
 So then I tried to start mysql with **service mysqld start** command, it is giving error -

**Timeout error occurred trying to start MySQL Daemon.**

I checked the logs with **tail -10 /var/log/mysqld.log** command, then it shows -

```
120714  6:48:02  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
120714  6:48:02  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120714  6:48:02  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 2096665
120714  6:48:02 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Error writing file '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid' (Errcode: 28)
120714  6:48:02 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: No space left on device
120714 06:48:02 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
120714 06:48:02 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
120714  6:48:03 [Note] Plugin 'ndbcluster' is disabled.
120714  6:48:03  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
120714  6:48:03  InnoDB: Completed initialization of b-bash-4.1
```

I am not understanding why this is happening. I am new to Linux and mysql.
Please guys help me to resolve this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type "df -h" to see how much space is left on /var/ mount point, could be that there's no space left in /var/?

Comment: Hi Howard for quick reply. When I run the "df -h" command it shows 

/dev/xvda1            6.9G  6.9G     0 100% /
tmpfs                1010M     0 1010M   0% /dev/shm

I dont knw what to do next?

Comment: Next you clean out your hard drive. :)

Comment: I see, so you are running a virtualized CentOS. It appears that you indeed have no space left. Try to delete some stuff form your disk or ask your VPS provider for a larger disk?

Comment: @Howards, Ok I'll delete some stuff and try to restart the mysql service. Thank You